# WSL+samba+git: "error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects" / git-clone / git-add permission errors

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, samba, git-add

I'm working on Win10 using the WSL1 (Windows Linux Subsystem) with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have a Samba (1.0) Network Share on which I want to create my git repository via my Ubuntu Terminal.

```
christian@my_pc:~/p/git_test$ ll
total 2048
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian  512 Jan 19 11:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian  512 Jan 19 10:11 ../
-rwxr--r-- 1 christian christian    0 Jan 19 10:12 my_code_file.rb
```

I can `git init` without a problem, however, as soon as I try to `git add` a file, I get this error:

```
christian@my_pc:~/p/git_test$ git add my_code_file.rb
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: my_code_file.rb: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file 'my_code_file.rb'
fatal: adding files failed
```

The permissions, however, are all right, as far as I can tell. All files belong to christian:christian. The tree looks like this:

```
.git
├── [-rwxr--r--]  HEAD
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  branches
├── [-rwxr--r--]  config
├── [-rwxr--r--]  description
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  hooks
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  commit-msg.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  post-update.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-commit.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-merge-commit.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-push.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  pre-receive.sample
│   ├── [-rwxr--r--]  prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └── [-rwxr--r--]  update.sample
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  info
│   └── [-rwxr--r--]  exclude
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  objects
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x]  e6
│   │   └── [-r-xr--r--]  tmp_obj_mZzHwy
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x]  info
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  pack
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  refs
    ├── [drwxr-xr-x]  heads
    └── [drwxr-xr-x]  tags

10 directories, 17 files
```

Whats strange is, that after `git add my_code_file.rb` I am no longer able to delete the `.git` dir, without permission error:

```
christian@my_pc:~/p/git_test$ rm -rf .git
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/e6/tmp_obj_mZzHwy': Permission denied
```

It seems git creates the `tmp_obj_mZzHwy` without giving me permission to delete it, which shouldn't be I guess.

Here again the permissions for the `.git` Folder after the `git add my_code_file.rb`

```
christian@my_pc:~/p/git_test$ ls -lahR .git
.git:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:14 objects

.git/objects:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:13 e6

.git/objects/e6:
total 1.0M
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 christian christian 512 Jan 19 11:14 ..
-r-xr--r-- 1 christian christian   0 Jan 19 11:13 tmp_obj_mZzHwy
```

The Samba Share on which I am working is mounted as drive (with letter P:) on Win10. On my WSL Ubuntu I mount it via `/etc/fstab` with following line:

```
P:▸ /mnt/p▸ drvfs▸defaults,metadata,rw,exec,uid=christian,gid=christian,umask=22,fmask=11▸0 0
```

My `.git/config` for the repo

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
```

What I already tried to fix the problem:

- `chmod -R u+rwx .`
- `git init --shared=all`
- `umask 0000`

On my home dir (resp. non-samba drive) `git init/add` works without problems.

---

### **Update**

I found out that the samba share is not mounted properly, the **metadata option is missing** resp. **gets ignored** whenever I mount it. I think this might be the problem! However, its not clear to me, why it's ignored or if there is **a way to force it?**

```
TARGET                       SOURCE      FSTYPE      OPTIONS
/                            rootfs      wslfs       rw,noatime
...
├─/mnt/p                     P:          drvfs       rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off
└─/mnt/c                     C:\         drvfs       rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,metadata,case=off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution: Upgrade to WSL2

As I found out, the solution was to **Upgrade from WSL1 to WSL2**, there mounting works correctly. I'm able to git-add or git-clone without permission errors now.

Open a PowerShell to see your current version:

```
PS C:\Users\christian> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         1
```

In case its 1 you can upgrade it, but check the WSL2 requirements first (just to be safe).

### [Upgrade Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-2---check-requirements-for-running-wsl-2)

**Excerpt from Guide/Steps I had to do:**

- [Check WSL2 Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-2---check-requirements-for-running-wsl-2) Windows above certain build resp. meets the requirements
- Download and execute: [WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package)
- Enable Windows Virtual Machine Platform Feature: `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`
- Reboot
- Upgrade your distro to WSL2: open Powershell and enter `wsl --set-version <distribution name> <versionNumber>`, in my case it was `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`. To see your distribution name type `wsl -l -v`
- Verify the upgrade with `wsl -l -v`

Just to provide complete information, here also the mount options `/etc/fstab`

```
P:      /mnt/p  drvfs   rw,noatime,uid=christian,gid=christian,metadata,case=off        0 0
```

Compared to

```
christian@my_pc:~$ findmnts
...
├─/mnt/p                        P:           9p          rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=P:;uid=1000;gid=1000;metadata;case=off;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=3,wfd=3
└─/mnt/c                        C:\          9p          rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=C:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;uid=1000;gid=1000;metadata;case=off;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=8,wfd=8
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of WSL2, you might still encounter another error because of the [built-in File System Monitor](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsmonitor--daemon) included with recent Git.

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), the built-in fsmonitor refuses to work on a network mounted repositories; a configuration knob for users to override this has been introduced.

See [commit 85dc0da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85dc0da6dcf21801149e747310d087abe26b2354) (11 Aug 2022) by [Eric DeCosta (`edecosta-mw`)](https://github.com/edecosta-mw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0479138](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04791386457e48220ee4388b9b3b51e36203d8c1), 13 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85dc0da6dcf21801149e747310d087abe26b2354): option to allow fsmonitor to run against network-mounted repos
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric DeCosta</sup>

> Though perhaps not common, there are use cases where users have large, network-mounted repos.
> Having the ability to run fsmonitor against network paths would benefit those users.
>
> Most modern Samba-based filers have the necessary support to enable fsmonitor on network-mounted repos.
> As a first step towards enabling fsmonitor to work against network-mounted repos, introduce a configuration option, '`fsmonitor.allowRemote`'.
> Setting this option to true will override the default behavior (erroring-out) when a network-mounted repo is detected by fsmonitor.

---

This comes from With Git 2.37 (Q2 2022), which clarifies the incompatibility with network drives:

See [commit 3294ca6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3294ca6140875163b538eab08b56d1c8b3ccca5b), [commit 53fcfbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53fcfbc84f68d11c9635fe58f72ce5a83200e051), [commit eb29901](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb299010eee63b5a069d82836efb38969ffd4109), [commit 00991e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00991e1013750130bbe4b4ac81279d6997935236), [commit 9915e08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9915e08f9bc4122a1d49101fff43be20a2ea6cb5), [commit d6d58ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d58ff8abd382226980f00360e12e4bf91456e4), [commit caa9c37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/caa9c37ec0b1c30ac1df266d01da6edb2c49d8ad), [commit f954c7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f954c7b8ff3f1443dfd52b5d0c59208a8d1d87ec), [commit 7667f9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7667f9d2ae944dbea85aeda7093af5c87904245c), [commit b533708](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5337082b34dbdb25f27014518841a6f78d82bf6), [commit 95a4e78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95a4e78a746be2b87972c03c82e8b1fe8fe0bea1), [commit de7e0b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de7e0b58ea4bb1ca8242e677096dae50f96e9b7e), [commit 6504cfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6504cfd392936f6e3994216101659fcda24ed1ac), [commit 90a70fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a70fa80964e7d582fb8df2c0115da79d13f5ab), [commit d060555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d06055501b0d31c417f8cbd237efb48065256d83), [commit 207534e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/207534e423d95861c27444d4cf9760bf16edc6c8), [commit 802aa31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/802aa31840bd2080f668d0efbaeea2021f4e2488), [commit 39664e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39664e93093bd9545ad4085523b122196c449508), [commit 8e8f4b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e8f4b814bab3f1499e50404e344f5b483c91f40), [commit 9968ed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9968ed73ff8bf00d06862e6653451faeb008afef), [commit ddc5dac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddc5dacfb368d4903f5dd475897e5e11772f9970), [commit d989b26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d989b266c1a7ef47f27cec75e90f3dfefbfa0200), [commit 1e7be10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e7be10de0d493f471bf102a7eed32da8247c825), [commit a85ad67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a85ad67bbdadb24ddb9b58a4010e20105c4c25e9), [commit 5c58fbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c58fbd26579391d825cb1ef0df8703bd6fd0ed5), [commit d33c804](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d33c804daec8aaf1e8af187c00166ef4cb017262), [commit 62a62a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62a62a28308453ee830bb7e02cf732474a6e01a5), [commit 49b398a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49b398a970f6efa368114330da23ae69aeeb9c60), [commit 27b5d41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27b5d4171d90073e37c7c1233b6bcc95ba58ae1d), [commit 40f865d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40f865dc025cfb91ee6338f688c06cdc65b53fa0) (26 May 2022) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
See [commit 852e2c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/852e2c84f847d99e29fd08feb8cea881dca63c79) (25 Mar 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9e496ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e496fffc872b20a147d7b80330335edfff919cc), 10 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor-settings`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddc5dacfb368d4903f5dd475897e5e11772f9970): NTFS and FAT32 on MacOS are incompatible
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> On MacOS mark repos on NTFS or FAT32 volumes as incompatible.
>
> The builtin FSMonitor used Unix domain sockets on MacOS for IPC with clients.
> These sockets are kept in the .git directory.
> Unix sockets are not supported by NTFS and FAT32, so the daemon cannot start up.
>
> Test for this during our compatibility checking so that client commands do not keep trying to start the daemon.

The [full comment](https://With%20Git%202.37%20(Q2%202022),%20more%20fsmonitor--daemon.%20%20See%20%5Bcommit%203294ca6%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/3294ca6140875163b538eab08b56d1c8b3ccca5b),%20%5Bcommit%2053fcfbc%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/53fcfbc84f68d11c9635fe58f72ce5a83200e051),%20%5Bcommit%20eb29901%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb299010eee63b5a069d82836efb38969ffd4109),%20%5Bcommit%2000991e1%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/00991e1013750130bbe4b4ac81279d6997935236),%20%5Bcommit%209915e08%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/9915e08f9bc4122a1d49101fff43be20a2ea6cb5),%20%5Bcommit%20d6d58ff%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d58ff8abd382226980f00360e12e4bf91456e4),%20%5Bcommit%20caa9c37%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/caa9c37ec0b1c30ac1df266d01da6edb2c49d8ad),%20%5Bcommit%20f954c7b%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/f954c7b8ff3f1443dfd52b5d0c59208a8d1d87ec),%20%5Bcommit%207667f9d%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/7667f9d2ae944dbea85aeda7093af5c87904245c),%20%5Bcommit%20b533708%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5337082b34dbdb25f27014518841a6f78d82bf6),%20%5Bcommit%2095a4e78%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/95a4e78a746be2b87972c03c82e8b1fe8fe0bea1),%20%5Bcommit%20de7e0b5%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/de7e0b58ea4bb1ca8242e677096dae50f96e9b7e),%20%5Bcommit%206504cfd%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/6504cfd392936f6e3994216101659fcda24ed1ac),%20%5Bcommit%2090a70fa%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a70fa80964e7d582fb8df2c0115da79d13f5ab),%20%5Bcommit%20d060555%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/d06055501b0d31c417f8cbd237efb48065256d83),%20%5Bcommit%20207534e%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/207534e423d95861c27444d4cf9760bf16edc6c8),%20%5Bcommit%20802aa31%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/802aa31840bd2080f668d0efbaeea2021f4e2488),%20%5Bcommit%2039664e9%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/39664e93093bd9545ad4085523b122196c449508),%20%5Bcommit%208e8f4b8%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e8f4b814bab3f1499e50404e344f5b483c91f40),%20%5Bcommit%209968ed7%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/9968ed73ff8bf00d06862e6653451faeb008afef),%20%5Bcommit%20ddc5dac%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddc5dacfb368d4903f5dd475897e5e11772f9970),%20%5Bcommit%20d989b26%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/d989b266c1a7ef47f27cec75e90f3dfefbfa0200),%20%5Bcommit%201e7be10%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e7be10de0d493f471bf102a7eed32da8247c825),%20%5Bcommit%20a85ad67%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/a85ad67bbdadb24ddb9b58a4010e20105c4c25e9),%20%5Bcommit%205c58fbd%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c58fbd26579391d825cb1ef0df8703bd6fd0ed5),%20%5Bcommit%20d33c804%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/d33c804daec8aaf1e8af187c00166ef4cb017262),%20%5Bcommit%2062a62a2%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/62a62a28308453ee830bb7e02cf732474a6e01a5),%20%5Bcommit%2049b398a%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/49b398a970f6efa368114330da23ae69aeeb9c60),%20%5Bcommit%2027b5d41%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/27b5d4171d90073e37c7c1233b6bcc95ba58ae1d),%20%5Bcommit%2040f865d%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/40f865dc025cfb91ee6338f688c06cdc65b53fa0)%20(26%20May%202022)%20by%20%5BJeff%20Hostetler%20(%60Jeff-Hostetler%60)%5D(https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).%20%20%20See%20%5Bcommit%20852e2c8%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/852e2c84f847d99e29fd08feb8cea881dca63c79)%20(25%20Mar%202022)%20by%20%5BJunio%20C%20Hamano%20(%60gitster%60)%5D(https://github.com/gitster).%20%20%20%3Csup%3E(Merged%20by%20%5BJunio%20C%20Hamano%20--%20%60gitster%60%20--%5D(https://github.com/gitster)%20in%20%5Bcommit%209e496ff%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e496fffc872b20a147d7b80330335edfff919cc),%2010%20Jun%202022)%3C/sup%3E%20%20%20%20%3E%20##%20%5B%60fsmonitor-settings%60%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddc5dacfb368d4903f5dd475897e5e11772f9970):%20NTFS%20and%20FAT32%20on%20MacOS%20are%20incompatible%20%20%20%3E%20%3Csup%3ESigned-off-by:%20Jeff%20Hostetler%3C/sup%3E%20%20%3E%20On%20MacOS%20mark%20repos%20on%20NTFS%20or%20FAT32%20volumes%20as%20incompatible.%20%20%20%3E%20%3E%20The%20builtin%20FSMonitor%20used%20Unix%20domain%20sockets%20on%20MacOS%20for%20IPC%20with%20clients.%20%20%20%3E%20These%20sockets%20are%20kept%20in%20the%20.git%20directory.%20%20%20%3E%20Unix%20sockets%20are%20not%20supported%20by%20NTFS%20and%20FAT32,%20so%20the%20daemon%20cannot%20start%20up.%20%20%20%3E%20%3E%20Test%20for%20this%20during%20our%20compatibility%20checking%20so%20that%20client%20commands%20do%20not%20keep%20trying%20to%20start%20the%20daemon.):

> ### Remote working directories are problematic for FSMonitor.
>
> The underlying file system on the server machine and/or the remote
> mount type (NFS, SAMBA, etc.) dictates whether notification events
> are available at all to remote client machines.
>
> Kernel differences between the server and client machines also
> dictate the how (buffering, frequency, de-dup) the events are
> delivered to client machine processes.
>
> A client machine (such as a laptop) may choose to suspend/resume
> and it is unclear (without lots of testing) whether the watcher can
> resync after a resume.
> We might be able to treat this as a normal
> "events were dropped by the kernel" event and do our normal "flush
> and resync" --or-- we might need to close the existing (zombie?)
> notification fd and create a new one.
>
> In theory, the above issues need to be addressed whether we are
> using the Hook or IPC API.
>
> For the builtin FSMonitor, we create the Unix domain socket for the
> IPC in the `.git` directory.
>
> If the working directory is remote,
> then the socket will be created on the remote file system.
> This can fail if the remote file system does not support UDS file types
> (e.g. smbfs to a Windows server) or if the remote kernel does not
> allow a non-local process to bind() the socket.
> (These problems
> could be fixed by moving the UDS out of the `.git` directory and to a
> well-known local directory on the client machine, but care should
> be taken to ensure that `$HOME` is actually local and not a managed
> file share).
>
> So (for now at least), mark remote working directories as
> incompatible.
>
> ### FAT32 and NTFS working directories are problematic too.
>
> The builtin FSMonitor uses a Unix domain socket in the `.git`
> directory for IPC.
> These Windows drive formats do not support
> Unix domain sockets, so mark them as incompatible for the daemon.

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), by default, use of fsmonitor on a repository on networked filesystem is disabled.
Add knobs to make it workable on macOS.

See [commit c4f9490](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4f94907902f18d80a78ee19983d0d02932154d7) (10 Oct 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 5aa9e32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aa9e3262e6ac99c1c06d7f0e0619b1ea94a9881), [commit 25c2cab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25c2cab08f90b6251b1ace91e37f05d4cb8fcd0c), [commit 12fd27d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fd27df79ac5f2589b54c8f36761d066dc9a97e), [commit 8f44976](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f44976882b77bb3b9ac0579a04ef05cbea5bdb2), [commit 6beb268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6beb2688d33373508610b190f04721e748caa12c), [commit 508c1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508c1a572d633202a220f2902c0d6b4cd1678349) (04 Oct 2022) by [Eric DeCosta (`edecosta-mw`)](https://github.com/edecosta-mw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7b8cfe3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b8cfe34d9b36a08214ea7e3ae82e9563188de5e), 17 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aa9e3262e6ac99c1c06d7f0e0619b1ea94a9881): add documentation for allowRemote and socketDir options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric DeCosta</sup>

> Add documentation for 'fsmonitor.allowRemote' and 'fsmonitor.socketDir'.
> Call-out experimental nature of 'fsmonitor.allowRemote' and limited filesystem support for 'fsmonitor.socketDir'.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5aa9e3262e6ac99c1c06d7f0e0619b1ea94a9881/Documentation/config/fsmonitor--daemon.txt#L1-L11):

> ### `fsmonitor.allowRemote`
>
> By default, the fsmonitor daemon refuses to work against network-mounted
> repositories. Setting `fsmonitor.allowRemote` to `true` overrides this
> behavior.  Only respected when `core.fsmonitor` is set to `true`.

`git fsmonitor--daemon` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5aa9e3262e6ac99c1c06d7f0e0619b1ea94a9881/Documentation/git-fsmonitor--daemon.txt#L73-L103):

> By default, the fsmonitor daemon refuses to work against network-mounted
> repositories; this may be overridden by setting `fsmonitor.allowRemote` to
> `true`. Note, however, that the fsmonitor daemon is not guaranteed to work
> correctly with all network-mounted repositories and such use is considered
> experimental.

---

And Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) fixes an issue where `core.fsmonitor` on macOS would not notice created or modified symbolic links.

See [commit ee0e7fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee0e7fc927c309e3ed1d46f7ba970b79d3a38514) (08 Nov 2022) by [srz_zumix (`srz-zumix`)](https://github.com/srz-zumix).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8d7b35b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d7b35b43df56bacd005492402c6a583284c0fec), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fsmonitor--daemon`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee0e7fc927c309e3ed1d46f7ba970b79d3a38514): on macOS support symlink
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: srz_zumix</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Resolves a problem where symbolic links were not showing up in diff when created or modified.
>
> `kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink` is also treated as a file update.
> This is because `kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile` is not included in `FSEvents` when creating or deleting symbolic links.
> For example:
>
> ```bash
> $ ln -snf t test
>     fsevent: '/path/to/dir/test', flags=0x40100 ItemCreated|ItemIsSymlink|
> $ ln -snf ci test
>     fsevent: '/path/to/dir/test', flags=0x40200 ItemIsSymlink|ItemRemoved|
>     fsevent: '/path/to/dir/test', flags=0x40100 ItemCreated|ItemIsSymlink|
> ```

Comment: Is there any workaround while waiting for the release of 2.38?

Comment: Actually my problem was due to some folder ownership not properly set to my WSL user under .git/objects (which I assume was due to a change of behavior in VS Code remote extension).
Solved with https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5179#issuecomment-979014877

Comment: @GGirard OK, good catch. Git 2.38 should be release early October in two weeks anyway.